# Populating data into python flask api endpoint for datatables.net

Tags: python, flask, datatables

Reading data from a csv into an API endpoint for datatables to fetch the data from the endpoint by ajax.

The python flask (**backend**) code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/fooditems')
def get_fooditems():
    df = pd.read_csv('fastfood.csv', usecols=["restaurant", "item", "calories"])
    json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')
    json_data = json.loads(json_data)
    print(json_data)
    return json_data


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('table.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The html and datatables/javascript (**frontend**) is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <table id="data" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Restaurant</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Calories</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>



 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#data').DataTable({
        ajax: '/api/fooditems',
        pageLength: 25,
        columns: [
          {data: 'restaurant'},
          {data: 'item'},
          {data: 'calories'}
        ],
      });
    });
  </script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Unexpected Output:**

When viewing the output json_data returned from the api endpoint (in the browser), it is in reverse order to the imported dataset. Then when viewing this in terminal the same data from the endpoint is in the correct order

Question

What is the correct way to prep the json_data for datatables, and why in this case is the order reversed?